# Recursive VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have two columns I am trying to match a VLOOKUP on cell G2. Column G is a long list of domain names. The value passed back is nested in a IF statement. Here is my code: `=IF(VLOOKUP(G2,'[SUBID Names.xlsx]Blacklist'!$A:$B,2,FALSE)=D2,"blacklisted","no")`

My issue is the data in the first column is not unique. I want to find if ANY of SUBID's (column B) match the found domain (which may show up multiple times) in the domain list (column A). If ANY match, I want the cell to contain the word "blacklisted". If none of the SUBID's match, or the domain was not found at all, I want the cell to contatin "no".

I've researched this. I think the answer might be in a vlookup array, but I'm not sure as the code I have seen for those is too complicated for me to figure out.

Data is contained in the sheet "SUBID Names.xlsx". Here is an example of the data:

```
Domain          SUBID
roblox.com      838242_11683801
tyrecompare.com.au  838242_11683801
verbacompare.com    838242_11683801
airbnb.com      663584_10197659
amazon.com      663584_10197659
etsy.com        663584_10197659
fandango.com        663584_10197659
roblox.com      663584_10197659
ebay.com        663584_10197659
roblox.com      11169468
amazon.com      11169468
ebay.com        11169468
```

Comment: You never attached that example of data...

Comment: `VLOOKUP` will **always** return the first matched value (reading top down)

Comment: @urdearboy yeah I know this. It is the reason why my formula is not working. I feel there is a solution out there, like an array vlookup that I mentioned or something else.

Answer (score 0):

`=IF(IFERROR(MATCH(G2&D2,INDEX(A:A&B:B,),0)>0,FALSE),"blacklisted","no")`

I'd recommend setting `A:A` and `B:B` to the actual data range, as this sort of operation on entire columns is expensive.